# Persistent counter, which survives application reinstalls

Tags: android

Is there a way to store a single value on an Android device, even if the application is uninstalled and reinstalled again?

As far as I found out, it's only possible if you provide some kind of web service and store the information on your server, as all application accessible storage is wiped on reinstall. Is this really true, or did I miss something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store it on the external storage (flash, sdcard). But this is easily manipulated or removed by the user since everyone can read or write it. In extreme cases the user can even take the card out of his device and read it with his cardreader. To prevent manipulation you can encrypt the information though.